# mysql query from subquery keeps hanging

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a mysql database and all I want is basically to get a value on the second table from a first table query

I have figured something like this but is not working.

```
select src, dst_number, state, duration 
from cdrs, area_code_infos
where SUBSTRING(cdrs.src,2,3) = area_code_infos.`npa`;
```

Please help me figure out this. I have tried in PHP to have multiple queries running one after the other but when I loaded the page after 45 minutes of wait time I gave up.

Thanks,

Comment: "but when I loaded the page after 45 minutes of wait" --- why do you think combining 2 queries may help? Having 1 query doesn't mean it will work twice faster than 2 queries.

Comment: I think you might be interested in knowing that `cdrs,area_code_infos` actually does the Cartesian product of the two tables. This is very expensive in terms of resources...

Answer (score 0):

I assume the tables are farily big, and you are also doing an unindexed query.. basically substring has to be calculated for every row.

Whenever you do a join, you want to make sure both of the joined fields are indexed.

An option would be to create another column containing the substring calculation and then creating an index on that.

However, a better option would be to have an areaCodeInfosID column and set it as a foreign key to the area_code_infos table